# How to stop update panel current process and call button click event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my **ASP.NET** page my users can check the customer balance before sending any payment. Balance update label is inside the Update Panel and sometimes it takes longer than usual to check the customer balance, so users might want to just cancel the checking and proceed to next step.

Is there any way to stop the current Update Panel event (while it's running and taking too long) and call some button Click event by using JavaScript?

Comment: Is this any use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398789(v=vs.100).aspx ?

Comment: Actually my goal is to cancel UpdatePanel's PostBack while it's running or if it's taking too long.

Comment: Isn't that what the link explains?

Comment: it disables the update panel loading image, but the page keeps waiting until the first request is done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution in C#. This code is put inside the code that updates the UpdatePanel control:

```
        Thread th = new Thread(DoSomething);
        th.Start();
        if (!th.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)))
        {
            th.Abort();
        }
```

If the UpdatePanel takes longer than 3 secs to update then it just aborts the current thread.

Comment: Does this answer your actual question "_call [a] button Click event by using JavaScript_"? Also, which HTTP response does it return to the browser from the AJAX request and does it cause a script error?

Comment: Yes, it does! In order to call the button click event from JavaScript you can just use: `document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_btnSubmit').click();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use code [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398789(v=vs.100).aspx) to cancel the refresh of the `UpdatePanel`.

```
var divElem = 'AlertDiv';
var messageElem = 'AlertMessage';

Sys.Application.add_load(ApplicationLoadHandler)
function ApplicationLoadHandler(sender, args)
{
     Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(CheckStatus);
}
function CheckStatus(sender, args)
{
  var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
  if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack() & args.get_postBackElement().id == 'CancelRefresh') {
     prm.abortPostBack();
  }
  else if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack() & args.get_postBackElement().id == 'RefreshButton') {
     args.set_cancel(true);
     ActivateAlertDiv('visible', 'Still working on previous request.');
 }
  else if (!prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack() & args.get_postBackElement().id == 'RefreshButton') {
     ActivateAlertDiv('visible', 'Retrieving headlines.');
  }
}
function ActivateAlertDiv(visString, msg)
{
     var adiv = $get(divElem);
     var aspan = $get(messageElem);
     adiv.style.visibility = visString;
     aspan.innerHTML = msg;
}
if(typeof(Sys) !== "undefined") Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
```

However, the processing of the ASP.NET request will continue in the background.

If the user cannot navigate until this is complete, it could be the ASP.NET session locking stopping your second request from starting until the first one is complete. You could try checking the [Response.IsClientConnected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525453(v=vs.90).aspx) property in the code of your first request and abort it if `false`. You may need to check this in a separate thread if your main thread is busy doing the processing, but it depends on the architecture of your application.

A simpler suggestion is to try disabling session, or setting it to read only if your page does not make use of it or write to it (quoted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3629757/413180)):

> If your page does not modify any session variables, you can opt out of most of this lock.
>
> `<% @Page EnableSessionState="ReadOnly" %>`
>
> If your page does not read any session variables, you can opt out of this lock entirely, for that page.
>
> `<% @Page EnableSessionState="False" %>`
>
> If none of your pages use session variables, just turn off session state in the `web.config`
>
> `<sessionState mode="Off" />`