# ASP.Net ReadOnly Session

Tags: asp.net, httpsession, inproc

I've conducted the following simple test:

1. In web.config, we have: `sessionState timeout=40 mode=InProc `
2. Empty page with `EnableSessionState = "ReadOnly"` set in page tag
3. Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Session["dt"] == null)
        Session["dt"] = DateTime.Now;

    Session["dt"] = ((DateTime)Session["dt"]).AddYears(1);
    Response.Write(Session["dt"].ToString());
}
```

The result for concurrent post backs will bee as the following:

```
1- 13/11/2015 10:00:00
2- 13/11/2016 10:00:00
3- 13/11/2017 10:00:00
4- 13/11/2018 10:00:00
5- 13/11/2019 10:00:00
6- 13/11/2020 10:00:00
...
```

Which clearly says that the session variable is getting updated. On MSDN you can find the following:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx

> You can disable session state for an application by setting the session-state mode to Off. If you want to disable session state for only a particular page of an application, you can set the EnableSessionState value in the @ Page directive to false. **The EnableSessionState value can also be set to ReadOnly to provide read-only access to session variables.**

We performs read/write operations on almost every page in our application. However, this is preventing running two http requests for the same client at the same time. The first request should be finished until the server process the second one. After some researches, it was clearly due to exclusive locks on session. For curiosity, we have tried to set session state to ReadOnly and it seems still editable which no exclusive locks are defined.

Questions:

1- Does Readonly means Readonly (so there is a bug in asp here) or it's something else?

2- As long as session seems to be editable with ReadOnly state, is there anything to worry about, do you think it's safe to keep using it like this on production environment?

Thanks

Comment: Just encountered the same scenario. A page marked with ReadOnly session to speed up AJAX requests, and Session is modifiable in that page. Have you confirmed with Microsoft that this is a bug?

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque it links to this question exactly!

Comment: @AhmadTh Oops! Not sure which question I meant to link, but this one is interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629709/i-just-discovered-why-all-asp-net-websites-are-slow-and-i-am-trying-to-work-out/42127199#42127199 "ASPNET session state can still be written to even in readonly mode and will not throw any form of exception (It just doesn't lock to guarantee consistency)"

Answer (score 3):

The ReadOnly flag indicates just your intention for the page/application. It **is not** a protection for the Session variable.

When you set ReadOnly on a page declaration you are just declaring the page will not update the Session variable. But if then you do it, it is at your own risk.

The declararion (and your behavior) helps ASP.NET to be faster. In fact, the session state module implements a locking mechanism and queues the access to state values.

A page that has **session-state write access** will **hold a writer lock** on the session until the request finishes. A page that has **session-state read access** will **hold just a reader lock** on the session until the request finishes**.

Declaring exactly the use of the session state that each page is going to make is a way to optimize the performance of the page and also a way to keep the code clean.

Finally you can completely disable the Session variable (both read and write) by setting:

```
<sessionState mode="Off">
```

but I do not think it is what you want.

Comment: As for MSDN, it is very true what you said about locks. However, when we tried the same configuration with SQL based session, the ReadOnly mode has resulted in read only session. Any modification on session in a page with ReadOnly flag will be just ignored. So this confirm that it's a bug :S

Comment: This is nice! I didn't know it

Answer (score 3):

This question seems old, but has quite a lot of views. Just wanted to give a warning to people using read-only session states and switching from InProc to SQLServer sessions.

While you can still put stuff in your session when it is read-only (without getting an exception), when using SQLServer sessions these changes are **not** committed to the database when the page has finished doing it's thing.

So the next page will **not** see your changes to the session, which may lead to strange side-effects if you used to have your session as InProc before and are expecting it to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Change the session settings:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" >
```

to

```
<sessionState mode="Off" >
```

I think you've nested web.config file so maybe this setting has been changed into another config file.

Comment: I don't want to disable the session. Just want to be aware of the "actual" impact of setting it readonly