# IIS8 MVC asp.NET Session not working. Getting null object reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session, iis-8

Can't get session variables working, I've tried all the solutions I could find online.

On page 1, I call the following in the c# model

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["lol1"] = "123";
```

Later on I use an ajax call to return this session variable to me in the c# model,

```
return HttpContext.Current.Session["lol1"].ToString();
```

In javascript, I pick it up in the ajax success function and put it in an alert box with alert(e);

I get an null object reference error. Seems like my variable didn't save into the session. This all works fine on localhost via debug, including the alert.

Things I have tried (currently set):

-DefaultAppPool setting Maximum Worker Processes: 1

-IIS manager->ASP->Services->Session Properties->Enable Session State:true

-IIS manager->Session State->In process

-In my solution web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="25"></sessionState>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="Session" />
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `SessionStateBehavior` in your controller.  For example:

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

It is recommended to use `ReadOnly` if you only need to read from `Session` and not write to it to prevent blocking.

Link to Microsoft's [SessionStateBehavior enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatebehavior(v=vs.110).aspx).

(for more info on ASP.NET's blocking when controllers use writable sessions see this link:  [Does Session State read/write everything when you access with DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35998252/does-session-state-read-write-everything-when-you-access-with-dynamodb/36103194#36103194))

Hope this helps!

Regards,

Ross

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need to write to it from the controller. That's where the data will come from in the first place

Comment: Try Default instead of ReadOnly then.

Comment: Put [SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Default)]

in my controller. Didn't fix it.. Thanks for the response.