# ASP .Net MapRequestHandler slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis

We have rolled out a classic ASP.Net WebService application with large traffic. Though our database is running quite well (<10 ms response times), most of the time spent in WebServer is in the MapRequestHandler stage.

[image: New Relic Request Breakdown]

[image]

The issue seems to be deep in the ASP .Net stack and without any information available on net, I am clueless as to how to go about improving it.

We use XML payloads for request/response (if that would help in providing a solution).

Comment: Forgot to mention, I tried to remove most of the Handler Mappings (in IIS) except .asmx and few others, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Please post you handler code and your config files.

> `MapRequestHandler` - The MapRequestHandler `event` is used by the ASP.NET infrastructure to determine
> request handler for the current request based on the file-name extension of the requested resource. `MapRequestHandler` is an `event` that the handlers need to implement, I suspect its stuck at some delegate that maps some custom file.

#### I suspect its `1`) *Not finding, looping around to find that custom file handler*, you may not `2`) using the `async handler`

You have to chase down the various `delegate` that use this `event` and setup a break point

Make sure they are `Async` & `Registered` for e.g.

```
<add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />    
<add verb="*" path="*.config" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />    
<add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory" />
```

Then under the handlers verify

```
<httpHandlers>

   <add verb="*" path="*.MyCustomaspx" type="MyCustomHTTPhandler"/>

</httpHandlers>
```

In your implementation use the `async` version base handler

```
 // dervie from Async HttpTaskAsyncHandler 
 public class MyCustomHTTPhandler: HttpTaskAsyncHandler {    
       public override Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)    
       {    
           //throw new NotImplementedException();    
           //blah blah.. some code
       }    
   }
```

---

*Last resort*, not recommended - from [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3629757/6085193), if your handler/page doesnt modify session variables, you can skip the session lock.

> ```
> <% @Page EnableSessionState="ReadOnly" %>
> ```

If your page does not read any session variables, you can opt out of this lock entirely, for that page.

> ```
> <% @Page EnableSessionState="False" %>
> ```

If none of your pages use session variables, just turn off session state in the web.config.

> ```
> <sessionState mode="Off" />
> ```

Based on this if you want to customize session state just based on your specific page/handler

---

```
using System;
using System.Web;   

public class CustomSessionStateModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose(){ //..  }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context){
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e){        
        HttpContext currentContext = (sender as HttpApplication).Context;
        // here you can filter and turn off/on the session state            
        if (!currentContext.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("My Custom Handler or Page Value")){
            // for e.g. change it to read only
            currentContext.SetSessionStateBehavior(
             System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly);
        }
        
        else {
            //set it back to default
            currentContext.SetSessionStateBehavior(
             System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Default);
        }    
     }
 }
```