# How to determine if you've got a session lock from your web application?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance, server, performancecounter

Web Application setup:

- .Net Framework 4.5.2
- SessionState Mode: SQLServer

I'd like to know how we can determine if the application got a session lock.

I tried using performance monitor but i don't know what are the performance counters needed and what exactly are the pointers that we can say that it's a session lock.

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server query lock or ASP.NET MVC session lock ?

Comment: @StepUp ASP.Net session lock

Comment: maybe it helps to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629709/i-just-discovered-why-all-asp-net-websites-are-slow-and-i-am-trying-to-work-out

Comment: @StepUp already saw that but it's not helpful to my question. what i'd like to know is how you can come up that the slowness of the site is caused by session lock. like does it logged an error to the server or what?

Comment: Try to ask here: https://forums.asp.net/1146.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to know the blocked Session Information-

```
SELECT session_id,        
   status,
        DB_NAME(database_id) [Database],
        blocking_session_id,
        wait_type,
        wait_time,
        wait_resource 
FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests
WHERE   blocking_session_id <> 0
GO
```

And to know some text regarding it use  the following query-

```
SELECT  A.Session_id,
        A.blocking_session_id,
        DB_NAME(B.database_id) [Database],
        C.text
FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests A
        LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests B ON A.blocking_session_id = B.session_id
        OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(B.sql_handle) C
WHERE   A.blocking_session_id <> 0
```